# Can't disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Tags: php, mysql, magento, stored-procedures

I am having an issue with **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY** on MySQL 5.7.14 where I can't seem to disable it even though I've set the SQL mode.

I have set both @@sql_mode to remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY by running this command:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

and I've also updated the my.cnf file to exclude it by setting the sql-mode param.

If I run `select @@sql_mode` I can see that ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY isn't set anymore.

However when I run my stored procedure I am still getting this error:

```
1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
nonaggregated column 'product_id' which is not functionally dependent on
columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

What am I missing here? Does the SP ignore the sql-mode?

I don't want to modify the SP code as it's been installed from a 3rd party module (for Magento) and that would cause issues if we wanted to upgrade.

This is on WAMP for my local dev server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For anyone that comes into the same problem,  it turns out that the sql mode is stored along with the stored procedure, so even though I have changed the sql mode correctly it doesn't update the SP at all. To fix this I just deleted and recreated the stored procedures while the new sql mode is set. It now works fine!

Comment: can you tell, how to delete and recreate stored procedure, for the same?

Answer (score 2):

To fix this drop and recreate the stored procedures
it's working .

USE `your_schema_name`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `your_sp_name`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `your_schema_name`$$
CREATE  PROCEDURE `your_sp_name`(IN `your_input` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

-- sp data here

END$$

DELIMITER ;